# Page div disappears when I collapse

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do facebook style message page. Everything was going smoothly. However, there was a problem. problem of sending the message at the bottom middle of the page. Page div disappears when I collapse.

This is my [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/FDtyp) page

Here is my **HTML** code

```
<div class="messages_area">
  <div class="kmes"></div>
    <div class="mrspbx">
     <div class="some-content-related-div">
       <div id="reply_content" class='conversationReply_grid'>

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
 <div class="mpare">
   <input type="hidden" id="cid" value="">
      <textarea name="update" id="update" maxlength="200" style="width:524px !important; "></textarea>
<input type="submit" value=" REPLY " id="update_button" class="reply_button repplybutton update_box"/> 
 </div>
</div>
```

And **CSS** code:

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}

.messages_area {
  float:left;
  position:fixed;
  width:500px;
  height:100%;
  border-right:1px solid #d8dbdf;
  margin-left:263px;
}
.kmes {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    heighrt:40px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #d8dbdf;
    margin-top:40px;
    }
.mrspbx {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    height:80%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position:relative;
    }
.mpare {
    left: 0;
    float:left;
    width:499px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #cdcecf;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:99;
    }
```

What i need to do here? Someone can help me ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "when I collapse?"

Comment: Narrow down demo page then see what is wrong dear. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @Jacob `.mpare` div height is `200px` but it looks not `200px`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is why `.mpare` does not look like it's `200px` tall, it actually is; however, it's overflowing outside of the container (`.messages_area`).

I take it from the `bottom: 0px` that you want it to appear at the bottom. In order for this to work, you'll need to change the positioning of `.mpare` so it's absolute. Adding a `position: absolute` to the CSS works for this.

**Update**:

To avoid `.mrspbx` overlapping `.mpare`, make .mrspbx `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 200px`. That way, it will take up all of the container except for the bottom `200px`.

Comment: yes it is true. I certainly tried this. but then another problem emerges. If i use for `.mpare` `position:absolute;`Does  messages area scroll  the problem occur. If you try this then you see dear.

Comment: `.mrspbx` `height:80%;` I think problem is there. But what is the solution?!

Comment: click this [link](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/FDtyp) then scroll down page.

Comment: I take it you want `.mrspbx` to not overlap `.mpare`. Since `.mpare` has a fixed height of `200px`, what worked for me is to make `.mrspbx` `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 200px`. That way, it will take up all of the container except for the bottom `200px`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the div ".mrspbx" is 80% high, and the rest of the content doesn't add up to 20% of the height. What that means is that when there is a lot of room, it all fits (so all that other content adds up to about 20% of the height), but when there is less room, the other divs add up to more than 20% of the height, so content gets shoved off the bottom of the page. Be careful when mixing percentages and fixed pixel attributes - it doesn't always mix well.

(Hope that was understandable...)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand what it is you want it to look like... "facebook style message page" is not quite descriptive enough. I would advise you to clean up your code (somewhere it says "heighrt" instead of "height"), and don't use `position: fixed` or even `position: absolute` too much - in case you want your site to work on a mobile device, `position: fixed` will probably not work well (if at all...) What helps me a lot when I'm coding a website are the Chrome Developer Tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index It can show you for example how wide a `div` _really_ is...